# how can I share iOS URl Schema with parameter to be a link that I can click not just string

Tags: ios, url-scheme

```
tazah://posts?postID=10
```

I need to make this a clickable link without using http

Answer (score 3):

You can open urls using this code

```
UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

So in your case:

```
if let url = URL(string: "tazah://posts?postID=10") {
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes this will open the app , but I want to share this to facebook or twitter and I can click it to open the app without using http or https as apple say "You cannot claim support for some well-known URL schemes, including http, https"

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no other way than deep linking. So the only way to achieve this is to redirect the user to http/s page like you red on apple documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the URL types scheme to your `info.plist`.

https://jayeshkawli.ghost.io/ios-custom-url-schemes/

Comment: you mean I can't make it without using http or https , because apple  say that "You cannot claim support for some well-known URL schemes, including http, https"

Comment: I think this answer is suggesting something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/72841869/199364. HOWEVER, that is only half of what is needed; also need a WEBSITE that handles that link, according to Apple's Universal Links doc. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78245939/199364) for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a comment on one of the answers, this is asking how to use Share to send  a clickable link to another app, where the link is a custom URI.

- It won't work to send a custom URI. There is no (general) way to tell other apps that is what you are sending. They will only receive a string.
- Instead, Follow apple's instructions for [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/).

1. This requires a web domain you control.
2. You send an `http` or `https` string that refers to a page on your website.
   E.g. if you owned `tazah.abc`, you send a string similar to `https://tazah.abc/posts?postID=10`.
3. Program both your website and your app according to Apple's instructions.

- It is still up to the receiving app whether to show a text string (or part of a string) that starts with `http://` or `https://` as a clickable link. Your app has no control over this.
- If there is a specific app you wish to send to, check whether that app has an API that gives you more control over the formatting of what you send.