# I faced a problem when I add firebase_core library to my flutter project and run "flutter build ipa"

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, webview, flutter-inappwebview

```
/* com.apple.ibtool.errors */
/Users/yazeedmohammad/Documents/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Storyboards/WebView.storyboard: error: Interface
Builder can’t determine the type of “WebView.storyboard”. This may be due to a missing SDK.
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Analyzing workspace
note: Constructing build description
note: Build preparation complete
```

Encountered error while archiving for device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64513759/12988168) to my problem and it's work fine alhamdullah.

solution link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64513759/12988168

solution:
"There is a Firebase documentation for iOS phone verification setup:

To enable the Firebase SDK to use reCAPTCHA verification:

Add custom URL schemes to your Xcode project:

Open your project configuration: double-click the project name in the left tree view. Select your app from the TARGETS section, then select the Info tab, and expand the URL Types section.
Click the + button, and add a URL scheme for your reversed client ID. To find this value, open the GoogleService-Info.plist configuration file, and look for the REVERSED_CLIENT_ID key. Copy the value of that key, and paste it into the URL Schemes box on the configuration page. Leave the other fields blank. When completed, your config should look something similar to the following (but with your application-specific values):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth?authuser=0

Works for Flutter too."